# Parsing drop down menu with php simple dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I want to parse this drop down menu with php simple dom.

```
<select name="example">  
    <option value="1">First example</option>  
    <option value="2">Second example</option>  
    <option value="3">Third example</option>
</select>
```

I need the values and the options for this drop down menu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($YOUR_XML_STRING);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$res = $xpath->query('//option');
for ($i = 0; $i < $res->length; $i++) {
    $node = $res->item($i);
    $value = $node->getAttribute('value');
    $content = $node->nodeValue;
}
```

With PHP simple dom :

```
    $html = str_get_html($YOUR_DROPDOWN_MENU);
    $opt = $html->find('option');
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($opt); $i++) {
        $element = $opt[$i];
        $value = $element->value;
        $content = $element->innertext;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! By php simple dom I mean "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser - http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/".

Comment: I added a version with php simple dom.

Answer (score 1):

for parsing and getting drop down select values with the help of simple html dom 
just try this simple code:

```
 $element =  $html->find('#selectIDGoesHere',0)->find('option');     
        foreach($element as $elemen) {         
            echo "Display text:".($elemen->plaintext)."<br>"; 
            echo "value:".($elemen->value)."<br>";
        }
```