# Finding the value of an option with specific string

Tags: php, forms, simple-html-dom

Consider this snippet from select form:

```
    <select name="cat_id"">
        <option  value="33">Apple</option>
        <option  value="44">Banana</option>
        <option  value="48">Carrot</option>
        <option  value="50">Dew</option>
        <option  value="77">Eggplant</option>
        <option  value="84">Fern</option>
        <option  value="92">Grass</option>
    </select>
```

Is there a way, using SIMPLE DOM, I can extract the value="x" for specific string.

Example, I want to get the value of **Dew**, hence, I must be able to get **50**
Tried searching and playing, but cannot find exact answer:

[Parsing drop down menu with php simple dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554440/parsing-drop-down-menu-with-php-simple-dom) <-- But values doesn't start from 0 nor increments uniformly

[php , simple_html_dom.php, get selected option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484103/php-simple-html-dom-php-get-selected-option) <-- I do not even have selected entry in the select form

I need to get the value for specific string so that I can use it to send form using cURL.

Hope, somebody can help. Thanks in advance and more power.

Comment: Ideally you want to be able to: `$doc->find('option[text()=Dew]', 0)->value` - simple can't do it but [this one can](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will parse all `option` nodes and when the searched text is matched, it will display the corresponding value and ends:

```
$input =  <<<_DATA_
    <select name="cat_id">
        <option  value="33">Apple</option>
        <option  value="44">Banana</option>
        <option  value="48">Carrot</option>
        <option  value="50">Dew</option>
        <option  value="77">Eggplant</option>
        <option  value="84">Fern</option>
        <option  value="92">Grass</option>
    </select>
_DATA_;

// Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($input);

// searched text
$searchText = 'dew';

// Create a regex pattern (match $searchText followed OR preceded by any number of spaces/tabs/newLines ...)
// i flag stands for case insensitive match
$pattern = '/\s*'.$searchText.'\s*/i';


foreach( $html->find('select[name="cat_id"] option') as $option ){
    echo $string = $option->plaintext;

    // Check if the current node contains the searched text
    if( preg_match($pattern, $string) ){
        $value = $option->value;

        echo ' => ' . $value;

        // Exit the loop when done
        break;
    }

    echo '<br>';
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Apple
Banana
Carrot
Dew => 50
```